# Index data under Solr from a SOAP web service to expose them via Search API (views)

Tags: search

We have to expose a subset of an external database coming via SOAP.
To keep it simple, let's say that we have to handle products, product providers and product categories under Drupal.
Products are search results candidates. Product providers and categories are search filters (e.g. facets).

Due to the amount of items, we decided to use Solr but are still opened to other solutions (Elastic Search, ...).
However, I do not think that the search solution has any incindence on the question.

A first solution is to cache the data from the web service into Drupal entities.

Pros :

- lowers the network load
- the whole Drupal ecosystem (Search API, Views, templates, ...) can be used as is
- the web service can be simplified (filters, pagination, ...)

Cons :

- write a sync mechanism (create, update, delete) between SOAP data and Drupal entities
- maintain an extra layer in case of change.

Any thoughts on this ?

Thanks